# Creating PowerQuery using forms created in Excel (data scattered)

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is the first time I have used Power Query and after copious amounts of research, I can't find the answer to my query. I am used to coding in Python but this had stumped me and I'm not sure of the limitations.

Essentially I have a form which is completed and saved down by colleagues but we need to create a database in the background to pull the outputs together. The form is not in standard tabular form. I have created a snip of the form [image] I need the columns to be e.g. cells D6, J6, T6, D8, J8, P8 etc and their corresponding values as E6, K6, U6, E8, K8, Q8.

Can this be done? TIA

Tried the normal route in Power Query but as expected, the data is not in the format as the import data isn't in tabular form.

Comment: easiest method is just create some cells off to the side with a range name that contains the desired cells adjacent to each other. Then combine them from all the sheets.  If you don't have that pre-populated,, I'd suggest running some VBA against existing files first

Comment: @horseyride thanks for your comment. I think that's the best route and will proceed as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard way in power query is to create a function to apply to each row which does the following: transpose the row to a column, add an index column, add another index column that is +1 of the first index column, then merge the table with itself by matching the index column with the index +1 column.

the function is created from:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\Form.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Sheet1_Sheet,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column7", "Column8", "Column13", "Column14", "Column17", "Column18"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Blank Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([Index] = DataRow)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Addition" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Addition", each [Index] + 1, type number),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Inserted Addition", {"Addition"}, #"Inserted Addition", {"Index"}, "Inserted Addition", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Inserted Addition" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Inserted Addition", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"}),
    #"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(#"Expanded Inserted Addition",1,1,1),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Alternate Rows", each [Column1] <> null and [Column1] <> ""),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Column1", "Column1.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1",{{"Column1", "Label"}, {"Column1.1", "Value"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

The key step pictured here

[image]

and the final query that calls the function is:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\Form.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Sheet1_Sheet,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column7", "Column8", "Column13", "Column14", "Column17", "Column18"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Blank Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "RearrangeRow", each RearrangeRow([Index])),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"RearrangeRow"}),
    #"Expanded RearrangeRow" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "RearrangeRow", {"Label", "Value"}, {"Label", "Value"})
in
    #"Expanded RearrangeRow"
```